# Continiously key down Event Pyqt

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt4

I make a script that in which i have lineedit and tool button . Button act as a backspace .Whenever a user click on button it will remove one letter from the lineedit .

Now i want that if i keep pressing (without releasing button) than it should keep removing single letter by letter text in line edit ( just like as we hold backspace on line edit it will remove letter one by one) .

I tried QKeyEvent and it do it one time and every time i need to press button to remove one letter .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any `Q*Button` class has this feature built-in. It's called [`autoRepeat`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractbutton.html#autoRepeat-prop). By default, this is disabled. But if you enable it, the button will fire `clicked` (and similar signals) continuously with certain intervals as long as it remains pressed.

You can fine tune the behavior with [`autoRepeatDelay`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractbutton.html#autoRepeatDelay-prop) and [`autoRepeatInterval`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractbutton.html#autoRepeatInterval-prop).